# (Objective-c) Hide specific windows

Tags: objective-c, macos

Hey, I was wondering if it's possible to make a mac os x app to hide specific windows that the user selects. I know how to make a button hide all windows and unhide all windows but I would like to know how to hide specific windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably somewhere you have references to your application's windows. From there you simply tell the window to `-orderOut:`.

Even if you aren't keeping track of your windows yourself, you can get a list of your application's windows by asking `[NSApp windows]`.

In a document-based app, you can get all the windows by their owning documents (there can be many windows per individual document) by asking: `[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] documents]` then asking each for its `-windowControllers`, then asking each window controller for its `-window`.

Comment: Could you write an example code? I'm still learning xcode and objective-c so that would help alot! Thanks

Comment: No I can't because you haven't provided enough detail, starting with stating which of the three possible scenarios I wrote about you are dealing with.

Comment: Presuming one would be in the second scenario, with windows created in interface builder, how would one come abouts to keep track of a window and how would one hide it? Thanks @Joshua Nozzi

Comment: @JeremiahSmith You should really post this as a separate question with specifics. It's a pretty broad topic to cover but, in general, you'll want to create outlets for any windows in some controller. In the case of a document-based application, the system creates everything in the document's xib/nib automatically when a document is opened/created. Just add a window, add an outlet to your document (or some other object) and connect it. You reference the window through the outlet.